# Fritz 7490 for 16 MB internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, adsl, fritzbox

I'm considering to get [Fritz 7490](http://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-7490/) for my home to get the most of my internet connection.

My internet connection is **16 Mbps** and I have a couple of devices: Laptop, iPad, iPhone, PS4 and smart TV.

But is Fritz 7490 is an overkill in my case or it is going to help me to get the most of my connection?

Comment: Your question is a bit off-topic here because it comes across as asking for hardware recommendations - which we don't do. Whatever box you choose will be overkill for your 16Mbps Internet connection... The Fritz! box devices do look like they have some good specs, though.... USB 3.0 and Wireless AC - to name but a couple... not a bad way to future-proof your home network...

Comment: @BigChris Thanks for answering. Why any box is an overkill in my case? 16Mbps is crappy? :-)

Comment: Well, depending on your location it may be the best connection available... but, in many other areas the connections (in the UK) can be 150MBps+...

Comment: @BigChris I was asked on other SE portals to ask my question on SuperUser.

Comment: You may have been directed to here as it's to do with computer hardware, but your question detail does not specifically mention a "problem" we can try to help with.. you appear to be asking our recommendations... which is off-topic :)

Comment: @BigChris I see your point. But I didn't ask for recommendations or suggestions. I asked about one specific device that I'm not sure about. Thanks again for help and time.

Comment: No problem :) The short answer is that yes, the box you mention will probably be fairly superb for your home network and will easily take your 16Mbps connection... From the specs the Fritz bozes can connect to VDSL lines (many of the high speed broadband connections use VDSL) so you've future proofed your home at least.

Comment: The DSL modem od the FB 7490 is definitely not going to be challenged by your 16 MBit/s line, but if you are going to use the other features of this device, it may still be a good choice. FB USB throughput is usually unimpressive and I read that this is also true for the 7490. The WLAN is also not top-notch. If you plan to rely on any of these two features heavily, other products may be more suitable.